# Craft 3 doesn't see my Commerce plugin

Tags: plugins, craft3

I am running a local install of Craft 3 Pro dev preview using MAMP and Sequel Pro on my iMac.  I downloaded the Commerce plugin to try it out and dropped the 'commerce' folder into my `craft/plugins` folder.  When I visit the admin control panel and click on plugins, I can't see the Commerce folder/plugin I just added. Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: The whole plugin API has gotten an overhaul in Craft3, so all plugins needs to be updated to work with Craft3. I'm pretty sure Commerce hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: @AndréElvan: Post that as the official answer... it's 100% correct.

Answer (score 4):

The whole plugin API has gotten an overhaul in Craft 3, so all plugins needs to be rewritten/updated to work with Craft 3.

Craft Commerce hasn't been updated yet. If it had there would be separate versions for Craft 2 and 3 for download.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that makes sense. (ps. I tried marking it as the official answer but don't see a green checkbox anywhere beside the answer so I'm not sure how to do it).

Comment: If you're the one who posted the original question, you're not logged in with the same user, that's the reason you can't mark it. :)